# Unable to click next on MIUI 8 Welcome Wizard due to dead screen area at bottom

Tags: broken-screen, miui

There is one non-rooted, factory-reset phone with MIUI ROM whose bottom 10% is not functional.

Screen replacement is the last resort, but if I can make some sort of software tweak to make it past the welcome screen to later root and use it for some unconventional use, it would be great.

Tried to find around following things but couldn't find the solution

1. Bypassing the welcome wizard
2. Force rotate device on the welcome screen

Any other suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Use otg connector and a mouse if some part of screen won't work

Comment: Thanks Kirandeep for the amazing idea! If the mouse with otg connector works without usb debugging enabled problem will be solved

Comment: It works without debugging in normal ui hope that works in wizard too